# Calculating interest rate for Perpetuities

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

So I have this homework question for actuarial mathematics:

**Two perpetuities have the same annual effective interest rate. Perpetuity A pays \$4 at the end of each year for the first 20 years and then $ 2 at the end of each year thereafter. Perpetuity B is a perpetuity due which has a level annual payment of \$ 3. At time t=0, the present value of Perpetuity A is equal to that of Perpetuity B. What is the effective annual interest rate, i?**

So what I've done is I calculated is let the present value of A equal to $$\sum_{n=1}^{20}(4/(1+i)^n +\sum_{n=20}^{\infty}(2/(1+i))^n$$
And the present value of B equal to $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(3/(1+i)^n)$$
Letting these equal, I got the interest rate $i$ to be equal to 3.35% which is wrong. Can anyone tell me where I've gone wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Is that not what a perpetuity is though? Going off to infinity?

Comment: Is the correct answer 3.526492% ?

Comment: No, still telling me it's wrong unfortunately, appreciate the help though, how did you come to that answer?

Comment: Could the second summation start at $n=21$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with your present value formulas.

For the first perpetuity, the second summation should start at $n=21$. That is because the payments of 2 don't start until the end of the 21st year.

For the second perpetuity, the summation should start at $n=0$. That is because it is a perpetuity *due*, meaning the first payment occurs immediately at time 0.

So the correct equation is:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{20}\frac{4}{(1+i)^n} + \sum_{n=21}^\infty \frac{2}{(1+i)^n} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{3}{(1+i)^n}.$$
Solving this, I find two real solutions $i \approx 4.23\%$ and $i \approx 33.11\%$.